# Max and Min sal with employee name in one query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm working on one SQL query.

Table name: `employees`.

I want to get the `MAX` and `MIN` sal with their employee names in SQL.

I know how to do with either `MAX` or `MIN`.  But how can we do it both in one query?

I need a single row output like below:

```
e1.name AS MaxName, MAX(e1.sal) AS MaxSalary, e2.name AS MinName, MIN(e2.sal) AS MinSalary
```

Comment: decide database tag first

Comment: You could use `UNION`.

Comment: Do you want your result as two records, or one record with two columns?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen,  I need one record with two columns. As two records i can do it by union..!! :)

Comment: 4 bits of information in two columns? What should the result look like?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ORACLE

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

Using **[Analytic](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm)** function:

```
SQL> SELECT  MIN(ename) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY sal) min_name,
  2          MIN(sal) AS min_sal,
  3          MAX(ename) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sal) AS max_name,
  4          MAX(sal) AS max_sal
  5  FROM    emp;

MIN_NAME      MIN_SAL MAX_NAME      MAX_SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
SMITH             800 KING             5000
```

Using an **In-line view**:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT MIN(sal) min_sal, MAX(sal) max_sal FROM emp
  3    )
  4  SELECT
  5    (SELECT e.ename FROM DATA t, emp e WHERE e.sal = t.min_sal AND ROWNUM =1
  6    ) min_name,
  7    (SELECT t.min_sal FROM DATA t, emp e WHERE e.sal = t.min_sal AND ROWNUM =1
  8   ) min_sal,
  9    (SELECT e.ename FROM DATA t, emp e WHERE e.sal = t.max_sal AND ROWNUM =1
 10   ) max_name,
 11    (SELECT t.max_sal FROM DATA t, emp e WHERE e.sal = t.max_sal AND ROWNUM =1
 12   ) max_sal
 13     FROM dual;

MIN_NAME      MIN_SAL MAX_NAME      MAX_SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
SMITH             800 KING             5000
```

Comment: I'm looking for like this  e1.name AS MaxName, MAX(e1.sal) AS MaxSalary, e2.name AS MinName, MIN(e2.sal) AS MinSalary. Just one record

Comment: @drill Done. See the update. Using an **inline view**. Please mark it as answered, would help others too!

Comment: you did that !! Thanks Alot !!

Comment: If there are two people who have the same min/max salary then the updated query will error with `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`.

Comment: @MTO To avoid the `ORA-01427` in the in-line query is to restrict the rows using `ROWNUM`. Updated with corrected query. That's the disadvantage of in-line view. Also not good in performance. FIRST and LAST are appropriate.

Comment: Just to nitpick, `keep ... first` has both aggregate and analytic versions, and this one (without an `over ()` clause) is the aggregate one, not analytic.

Answer (score 1):

In a single select:

```
SELECT  MIN( salary ) AS MinSalary,
        MIN( name ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY salary ASC ) AS MinName,
        MAX( Salary ) AS MaxSalary,
        MAX( name ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY salary ASC ) AS MaxName
FROM    Employees;
```

Comment: It is not handling duplicate salaries properly.Two or more employees with maximum salary and/or two or more employees with minimum salary, it will display partial result.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for MySQL, which was one of the tags you originally had when you posted your question.

You can perform a `CROSS JOIN` of the `employees` table against itself to find the max name/salary with a query which finds the min name/salary.

```
SELECT e1.name AS MaxName, MAX(e1.sal) AS MaxSalary,
    e2.name AS MinName, MIN(e2.sal) AS MinSalary
FROM employees e1 CROSS JOIN employees e2
```

Click the link below for a running demo.  I actually include the name/salary pairs, though you can remove the names if you don't want them there.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1df8fe/3)

Comment: @Tim, Not working. ORA-00937 "not a single-group group function"

Comment: Why didn't you tag your question with Oracle?

Comment: Am I going in wrong direction ? query requirement makes sense or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
select max(sal), min(sal), employee_id 
from employees
group by employee_id;
```

After that you can join it to get the name. Maybe you can group by name and id too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Oracle, try this. Here first we are getting rownumber in ascending and descending order and then doing a cross join.

```
with employee(id,name,sal) as
(select 1,'a',1000 from dual union all
select 3,'c',1500 from dual union all
select 2,'b',2000 from dual)   --temp table to recreate the scenario
, enew as(
select e.*,row_number() over (order by sal) as salasc,row_number() over (order by sal desc) as saldesc from employee e
) --temp table to find the rownumber in ascending and descending order
--original query
select * from (select id as minsalid,name as minsalempname,sal as minsal from enew
where salasc=1)
cross join
(select id as maxsalemp,name as maxsalempname,sal as maxsal from enew
where saldesc=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with min_max_age as
  (
    select dept,
    min(age) as  min_Age,
    max(age) as max_age
    from Employees
    group by dept
  )
select a.name, a.dept, a.age from Employees a join min_max_age b
on (a.age = b.min_Age and a.dept = b.dept)
or (a.age = b.max_age and a.dept = b.dept)
```